# How to pass string from data class to ContentDialog

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

How can I pass a string value from my data class to a content dialog when a button in my master list view is clicked? Is there a way to do this without having to use dependency properties in this case or should something else be used?

**Expected result**

[image]

[image]

**Current app layout**

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MD.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MD"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView x:Name="MyMasterDetailsView"
                                    BackButtonBehavior="Automatic" 
                                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"
                                    NoSelectionContent="Select an item to view"
                                    CompactModeThresholdWidth="720">
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Opacity=".6"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                x:Name="MoreBtn" 
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Content="&#xE712;" 
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="10" 
                                Padding="10" 
                                Click="MoreBtn_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel Margin="24">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Margin="12,-6,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Body" 
                                   Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform 
                                  ScaleX="2" 
                                  ScaleY="2"/>
                            </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </SymbolIcon>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   Margin="0,12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>

                    <CommandBar.Content>
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,14">
              <Run Text="{Binding Emails.Count}" />
              <Run Text="Items" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </CommandBar.Content>
                </CommandBar>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailReply" Label="Reply" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailReplyAll" Label="Reply All" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailForward" Label="Forward" />
                </CommandBar>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Item class (Email)**

```
public class Email
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
    public string DialogTitle { get; set; }
    public string DialogContent { get; set; }
}

public class MyEmailManager
{
    public static List<Email> GetEmails()
    {
        var MyEmails = new List<Email>
        {
            new Email
            {
                From = "Steve Johnson",
                Body = "Are you available for lunch tomorrow? A client would like to discuss a project with you.",
                ShowButton = true,
                DialogTitle = "Title A",
                DialogContent = "Content A"
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Pete Davidson",
                Body = "Don't forget the kids have their soccer game this Friday. We have to supply end of game snacks.",
                ShowButton = false,
                DialogTitle = "",
                DialogContent = ""
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "OneDrive",
                Body = "Your new album.\r\nYou uploaded some photos to your OneDrive and automatically created an album for you.",
                ShowButton = false,
                DialogTitle = "",
                DialogContent = ""
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Twitter",
                Body = "Here are some people we think you might like to follow:\r\n.@randomPerson\r\nAPersonYouMightKnow",
                ShowButton = true,
                DialogTitle = "Title D",
                DialogContent = "Content D"
            }
        };

        return MyEmails;
    }
}
```

**Page class**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Binding myBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Source = Emails,
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
            };

            MyMasterDetailsView.SetBinding(MasterDetailsView.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);

            var emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
            emails.ForEach(email => Emails.Add(email));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Email> Emails = new ObservableCollection<Email>();

        private async void BtnMoreMasterItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentDialog MyDialog = new ContentDialog
            {
                Title = Emails.DialogTitle,
                Content = Emails.DialogContent,
                CloseButtonText = "OK"
            };

            ContentDialogResult result = await MyDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong about passing values through `Content` and `Title` props of the `ContentDialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to pass string from data class to ContentDialog

For this scenario, you could bind `MoreButton` [`Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand?view=winrt-19041) property and pass current `DataContext` as method parameter with `CommandParameter`.

For example.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    Emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
}

public ICommand OpenDialog
{
    get
    {
        return new CommadEventHandler<Email>((s) => OpenDialogCommandFun(s));
    }
}
private async void OpenDialogCommandFun(Email s)
{
    ContentDialog dialogServiceUpdates = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = s.From,
        Content = s.Body,
        CloseButtonText = "OK"
    };

    ContentDialogResult result = await dialogServiceUpdates.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Button
    x:Name="MoreBtn"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10"
    Padding="10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Background="Transparent" 
    Command="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=DataContext.OpenDialog}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
    Content="&#xE712;"
    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
    Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, Converter={StaticResource MyConveter}}"
    />
```

For better understanding, I have uploaded the code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MasterDetailViewTest), please check it.

Comment: The `MoreBtn_Click` event is empty, nothing happens when the button is clicked. What needs to go in there?

Comment: @MacaronLover, Do you have any updates for this thread?

Comment: MoreBtn_Click event replaced by command method. You just place the process logic in the `OpenDialogCommandFun` method.

Comment: Removing the click event didn't make any difference

Comment: It works now after cleaning & rebuilding my project but didn't before, don't know why but thanks for your help.